# grep with regex crop text

Tags: regex, shell, grep

I have a file.txt which looks like

```
dfvdfvdf
lot of stuff I don't care
fdvdegghedc
Run test suite LogicTests
ffdvfvdf
fdvdfvdf
fhtrefg
```

And I want to get everything from Run test suite LogicTests to the end of the file
So I do as follow

```
resultCroped=$(grep -E 'Run test suite LogicTests[\n.*]' file.txt)
```

but that doesn't seems to be the good regex

help please thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sed` would be more appropriate for this kind of task:

```
sed -n '/^Run test suite LogicTests$/,$p' <file>
```

This will print all the lines from the regular expression match to the end of the file as asked.

Answer (score 2):

an awk variant:

```
awk '/Run test suite LogicTests/{o=1}o' yourFile
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `grep -A 1000 'Run test suite LogicTests'` which will return you 1000 lines after the string you're seeking for.